# Python 2.7 pylab on mac 10.8 (infinity run)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Please, could anyone explain why this code:

```
import pylab
pylab.figure(1)
pylab.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,7,3,5])
pylab.show
```

is executed on my Mac OS 10.8 the rocket icon start to jumping on Dock, but nothing happened?

P.S. I've already download Python 2,7 for 32 bit, for 64 bit, download EPD, but the same problem everywhere ((

Here video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faSyAKPpr4A&feature=youtu.be

Please, if someone know what is It, explain.

Comment: use pylab.show() not pylab.show

Comment: @AlexGaudio -- you should post that as an answer. (with a short explanation that you need to *call the function* and you need parens in order to do that)

Comment: Yeh, It's my fault here, but in code I do all right in syntax, what the problem with soft/service on my mac, why it want run figure (but is save .png when I call savefigure method)

Comment: Try running an ipython session with pylab: `ipython --pylab`. When you call `figure()`, a window should appear straight away. If not, then maybe something is fishy with the OSX Matplotlib backend. Did you try deleting matplolib's directory (in a Mac, `~/.matplotlib/`)?

Comment: thx, but It didn't help(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same prolem. Try to install freetype:

```
sudo port install freetype
```

with MacPorts, or, for example,

```
brew install freetype
```

with brew.